# Get the value from a custom field in category

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a custom field in admin category interface named custom order. It is showing in the admin. But now I am having difficulties in **getting** the information from the field and echo it in `index.php`.

If I run

```
$thisCat = get_category( 29);
    print_r($thisCat);
```

I don't get any information from the custom field.

`echo get_post_custom_values('category_custom_order', 29);` doesn't echo anything.

How should I get the value from `category_custom_order`?

Here is my code for custom field in `functions.php`:

```
<?php
/** Add Custom Field To Category Form */
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'category_form_custom_field_add', 10 );
add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'category_form_custom_field_edit', 10, 2 );

function category_form_custom_field_add( $taxonomy ) {
?>
<div class="form-field">
  <label for="category_custom_order">Custom Order</label>
  <input name="category_custom_order" id="category_custom_order" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" />
  <p class="description">Enter a custom order value.</p>
</div>
<?php
}

function category_form_custom_field_edit( $tag, $taxonomy ) {

    $option_name = 'category_custom_order_' . $tag->term_id;
    $category_custom_order = get_option( $option_name );

?>
<tr class="form-field">
  <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="category_custom_order">Custom Order</label></th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="category_custom_order" id="category_custom_order" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $category_custom_order ) ? esc_attr( $category_custom_order ) : ''; ?>" size="40" aria-required="true" />
    <p class="description">Enter a custom order value.</p>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php
}

/** Save Custom Field Of Category Form */
add_action( 'created_category', 'category_form_custom_field_save', 10, 2 ); 
add_action( 'edited_category', 'category_form_custom_field_save', 10, 2 );

function category_form_custom_field_save( $term_id, $tt_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['category_custom_order'] ) ) {           
        $option_name = 'category_custom_order_' . $term_id;
        update_option( $option_name, $_POST['category_custom_order'] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it this way, and by the way it's not a custom field but an option.

```
$category_id = 29;
$category_custom_order = get_option( 'category_custom_order_' . $category_id );

echo $category_custom_order;
```